# Quicksight Pivot table: How to calculate Consumption% based on gender and age group with brand filters and custom calculations?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a problem in Quicksight.

To explain my problem, I use the below sample database.

INDIVIDUAL_ID   DATE    DRINKS(L)   BRAND   GENDER  AGE_GROUP
1   20230509    100 A   F   1
1   20230509    150 B   F   1
2   20230509    200 D   M   2
2   20230509    120 E   M   2
2   20230509    90  A   M   2
3   20230509    220 B   F   3

I want to create a Pivot table as follows

BRAND   Sum of DRINKS   Consumption %
A   190          21.6
B   370          42.0
D   200          22.7
E   120          13.6

When calculating the consumption%, it should calculate based on the total consumption based on the GENDER and AGE_GROUP selection.

User should be able to filter the Pivot table from any number of BRANDs as well.

Eventhough user filter from BRAND, consumption% should needs to calculate based on the GENDER & AGE_GROUP selections only.

Can anybody help to get the Consumtion% for my requirement please.